# 512 bytes length vertex shaders not supported

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vertex-shader, shading

I'm working on a simple game based on shaders and as my vertex shader file grew up, its size reaches 512 bytes and I'm now unable to load it in c++..
I don't think it is a common issue but I guess it comes from my custom shader loader and not from opengl limitations.
Here the code of my simple vertex shader (it is supposed to map cartesian coordinates to spherical ones, its size is 583bytes):

```
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 camera;

layout (location=0) in vec3 vertex;
layout (location=1) in vec4 color;

in mat4 object;

out vec4 vColor;

void main()
{
  float x=sqrt(max(1.0-0.5*pow(vertex.y,2)-0.5*pow(vertex.z,2)+pow(vertex.y*vertex.z,2)/3.0,0.0));
  float y=sqrt(max(1.0-0.5*pow(vertex.x,2)-0.5*pow(vertex.z,2)+pow(vertex.x*vertex.z,2)/3.0,0.0));
  float z=sqrt(max(1.0-0.5*pow(vertex.x,2)-0.5*pow(vertex.y,2)+pow(vertex.x*vertex.y,2)/3.0,0.0));
  gl_Position=projection*camera*object*vec4(x,y,z,1.0); 
  vColor=color;
}
```

And the code of the loader:

```
GLuint vs;
vs=glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
std::ifstream vertexShaderStream(_vsPath);
vertexShaderStream.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
unsigned int vsSourceLen=(unsigned int)vertexShaderStream.tellg();
vertexShaderStream.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
char vertexShaderSource[vsSourceLen];
vertexShaderStream.read(vertexShaderSource,vsSourceLen);
vertexShaderStream.close();

const char *vsConstSource(vertexShaderSource);
glShaderSource(vs,1,&vsConstSource,NULL);
glCompileShader(vs);
int status;
glGetShaderiv(vs,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&status);
if(!status)
{
    char log[256];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vs,sizeof log,NULL,log);
    std::cout << log << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

When I reduce the size below 512bytes(2^9...) (511 and less) It works well.
I'm using GLFW3 to load openGL.
Did you ever seen a problem like that?

Comment: Does `char vertexShaderSource[vsSourceLen];` even compile? A stack array may only be declared with a **size known at compile time** but `vsSourceLen` is definitely not known at compile time.

Comment: @BDL That's not in standard C++, but we all know it's a common extension.

Comment: what error do you get opengl?

Comment: Yeah I’ve already changed the y to z which was just a mistake I did in this post. OpenGL throw a weird error “‘= syntax error syntax error”

Answer (score 5):

One issue is that you're reading your shader source into a `char[]` buffer with `read`, without ever adding a NUL terminator, and then you call `glShaderSource` with NULL for a length vector, so it will look for a NUL terminator to figure out the length of the string.  So I would expect that to randomly fail, depending on what happens to be in memory after the string (whether it luckily appears as NUL terminated, because the next byte happens to 0 or not).

You need to either properly NUL terminate your string, or pass a pointer to the length of the string as the 4th argument to `glShaderSource`

Comment: In fact it finally worked whitout specifying the size but you’re right that this is playing lottery and I finally set it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Adding std::ifstream::binary as a second parameter in the ifstream constructor solved the issue. I don’t exactly understand why the ifstream, which by default treat files as text files, stops to count end of line when the length of the file reaches 512 bytes and adds some random bytes to match the actual size. Anyway, using ifstream is certainly not the best way to load files but as far as it is just to deal with shaders I would say this is ok  (with the appropriate “ios::binary” flag).

Comment: That's because `ftell` and friends do _not_ return byte offsets in text streams.